# Understanding concepts and notation in basic acoustic equations

Tags: acoustics, notation

I am reading a book describing the physics of acoustic sound waves. I stumbled across the equations:
$$\text{grad }P = -\rho_0\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$$
$$\rho_0\text{ div }V = \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$$
"here $P$ denotes the sound pressure, $V$ the vector particle velocity, $t$ the time
and $\rho_0$ the static value of the gas density."

Is "vector particle velocity" a discrete vector where each entry describes the velocity of a single particle? Or is it a vector with the average velocity? Or a third option I did not take into account?

Also, what does the 'div' operation? is it division? is it divergence?

Is it common not to specify such things and I am supposed to understand from the context? If so, how?

Comment: Have you ever seen "$\text{div}$" to be division? Have you ever performed division on a single number?

Comment: Sure I have. $\rho_0\text{ div } V$ could be $\frac{\rho_0}{V}$. If I am searching "div" in Wikipedia that is the first result. Are you saying it could not be? If so, what am I missing?

Comment: $div$ will always mean divergence.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. but is it a divergence with respect to $(x,y,z)$? or is $V$ a function of $t$ as well and needs to be differentiated with respect to time?

Comment: The divergence of a vector is always with respect to spatial coordinates. I suggest you reinforce vector calculus concepts before studying this.

Comment: I will do so. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Most advanced physics textbooks have either mathematical appendices or an introductory chapter on math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it common not to specify such things and I am supposed to understand from the context? If so, how?

Both approaches are common. Sometimes the author presents the required math in a first chapter or in an appendix. Other times, the author discusses the prerequisites of the book in the preface/introduction. In your case, the notation is widely used so I would not expect the author to stop and discuss it.

I would summarize some of the comments:

- $\operatorname{div}$ is the divergence of a (vector) field and the notation $\nabla\cdot$ is also common.
- $\operatorname{grad}$ is the gradient of a (scalar) field and the notation $\nabla$ is also common.

Regarding the two equations that you present:

- the first one represent the conservation of (density of) momentum; and
- the second one represents the conservation of mass.

That is the most important physical relevance of those two.